# Importing package namespace into default namespace

Tags: r, namespaces

Frequently when I am working with R and I want to find out what the function does, I type in the name of the function and scroll through the code. However, sometimes when I type in the name of the function I get a response that does not tell me anything.

```
> library(limma)
> plotMDS #can't get to the code
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("plotMDS")
<environment: namespace:limma>
> limma:::plotMDS
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("plotMDS")
<environment: namespace:limma>
> heatmap #im expecting something more like this
function (x, Rowv = NULL, Colv = if (symm) "Rowv" else NULL, 
    distfun = dist, hclustfun = hclust, reorderfun = function(d, 
        w) reorder(d, w), add.expr, symm = FALSE, revC = identical(Colv, 
        "Rowv"), scale = c("row", "column", "none"), na.rm = TRUE, 
    margins = c(5, 5), ColSideColors, RowSideColors, cexRow = 0.2 + 
        1/log10(nr), cexCol = 0.2 + 1/log10(nc), labRow = NULL, 
    labCol = NULL, main = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, keep.dendro = FALSE, 
    verbose = getOption("verbose"), ...) 
{
    scale <- if (symm && missing(scale)) 
        "none"
    else match.arg(scale)
/* ... many lines removed ... */
    }
    invisible(list(rowInd = rowInd, colInd = colInd, Rowv = if (keep.dendro && 
        doRdend) ddr, Colv = if (keep.dendro && doCdend) ddc))
}
<bytecode: 0x16199b8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Thus, I was wondering if there is a way to import a package's namespace into the default namespace so I can look at code in functions (and debug things easier). I've been reading up on namespace but most of the time it is written for developers so it is talking about how to export namespaces for packages.

Comment: you're right. This solved my problem of reading code but still wondering if its possible to put the whole package namespace into default namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really crude alternative, but it does what was requested:

Firstly, copy the contents of the namespace to a list in the global environment:

```
L <- as.list(asNamespace("yourpackage"))
```

Now you can either navigate `L` or copy all its contents to equally named objects in the global environment with this:

```
invisible(lapply(names(L), function(x) eval(parse(text=paste0(x,"<-L[['",x,"']]")), globalenv())))
```

warning: this will overwrite whatever object you have defined with the same name! So use with care.

Comment: better use `all.names=TRUE` if you're gonna do that.

Comment: where it should be placed?

Comment: In the `as.list` call

Comment: In light of `fortunes::fortune(106)` (If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.) how about this: `L <- as.list(getNamespace("yourpackage"), all.names=TRUE); for (i in seq_along(L)) assign(names(L)[i], L[[i]], pos=globalenv())`

Comment: @GSee, I agree, this is a crude solution to a badly posed problem. BTW, your code is better (or less worse) than mine. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`plotMDS` is the generic function. What you access via `plotMDS` and `limma:::plotMDS` is exactly the same thing, the latter just less-efficiently. What you want to get at are the **methods** for this generic function.

To see the list of method for `plotMDS` try

```
methods(plotMDS)
```

That will return a vector of function names. I can't install **limma** so here is what we see for the base `plot` generic [in my current session]:

```
> methods(plot)
 [1] plot.acf*            plot.correspondence* plot.data.frame*    
 [4] plot.decomposed.ts*  plot.default         plot.dendrogram*    
 [7] plot.density         plot.ecdf            plot.factor*        
[10] plot.formula*        plot.function        plot.hclust*        
[13] plot.histogram*      plot.HoltWinters*    plot.isoreg*        
[16] plot.lda*            plot.lm              plot.mca*           
[19] plot.medpolish*      plot.mlm             plot.ppr*           
[22] plot.prcomp*         plot.princomp*       plot.profile*       
[25] plot.profile.nls*    plot.ridgelm*        plot.spec           
[28] plot.stepfun         plot.stl*            plot.table*         
[31] plot.ts              plot.tskernel*       plot.TukeyHSD       

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

To access the code of non-starred functions we just enter the full function name, e.g.

```
> plot.density
function (x, main = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = "Density", type = "l", 
    zero.line = TRUE, ...) 
{
....
```

To see the code for starred functions/methods you need the `pkg:::function` structure, e.g. for the `plot.data.frame` method

```
> plot.data.frame
Error: object 'plot.data.frame' not found
> graphics:::plot.data.frame
function (x, ...) 
{
 ....
```

If you don't know which namespace a method belongs to, then use `getAnywhere`, e.g.

```
> getAnywhere(plot.data.frame)
A single object matching ‘plot.data.frame’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for plot from namespace graphics
  namespace:graphics
with value

function (x, ...) 
{
....
```

The printed results indicate the relevant namespace (in this case `graphics`) plus return the value of the function, or the code.

Comment: yup this works, but still a bit curious about the pkg namespace -> default namespace
```
> methods(plotMDS)
[1] plotMDS.default plotMDS.MDS    
> getAnywhere(plotMDS.MDS)
A single object matching ‘plotMDS.MDS’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:limma
  registered S3 method for plotMDS from namespace limma
  namespace:limma
with value

function (x, labels = colnames(x$distance.matrix), col = NULL, 
    cex = 1, dim.plot = x$dim.plot, xlab = paste("Dimension", 
        dim.plot[1]), ylab = paste("Dimension", dim.plot[2]), 
    ...) 
{
/* more code here*/
```

Comment: There isn't a "default" namespace. All packages now must have their own namespace. It is up to the individual package maintainers to decide what is exported (i.e. visible) and what is not exported (i.e. not visible).